# After upgrade to 18.04 logwatch no longer tracks fail2ban correctly

Tags: upgrade, 18.04

With 16.04.5, my logwatch reports showed a nice, clean fail2ban section.  After upgrading to 18.04.1, there is now an "** ERRORS **" section at the end of the fail2ban report that begins with:

```
** ERRORS ** 
7fa492aac3a0 -- stderr: '   ERROR: Shorewall is not started': 1 Time(s) 
7fa7506add00 -- stderr: '   ERROR: Shorewall is not started': 2 Time(s) 
7fa752ec2080 -- stderr: '   ERROR: Shorewall is not started': 1 Time(s) 
7fa752ef9490 -- stderr: '   ERROR: Shorewall is not started': 4 Time(s) 
Failed to execute ban jail 'sshd' action 'shorewall' info 'ActionInfo({'ip': '216.214.177.133', 'family': 'inet4', 'ip-rev': '133.177.214.216.', 'ip-host': 'static-216-214-177-133.isp.broadviewnet.net', 'fid': '216.214.177.133', 'failures': 3, 'time': 1533669518.3297515, 'matches': 'Aug  7 15:09:55 mail sshd[63840]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=216.214.177.133\nAug  7 15:09:57 mail sshd[63840]: Failed password for invalid user eden from 216.214.177.133 port 57260 ssh2', 'restored': 1, 'F-*': {'matches': ['Aug  7 15:09:55 mail sshd[63840]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=216.214.177.133', 'Aug  7 15:09:57 mail sshd[63840]: Failed password for invalid user eden from 216.214.177.133 port 57260 ssh2'], 'failures': 3, 'mlfid': ' mail sshd[63840]: ', 'user': 'eden', 'ip4': '216.214.177.133'}, 'ipmatches': 'Jun  4 17:09:11 mail sshd[12089]: Invalid user munkanaplo from 216.214.177.133\nJun
```

and continues on for a page or two (because the insanely long line [that I massively truncated in my example] is wrapped into the report display.)

Any ideas on why this is happening, what I can do to fix it or if it is a problem introduced into logwatch?

In 16.04.5, logwatch reported version 7.4.2 and, unfortunately, I do not have the fail2ban version handy, but it was up-to-date according to apt.

In 18.04.1, logwatch reports version 7.4.3 and dpkg shows that fail2ban 0.10.2-2 is installed.

--EDIT--
After monitoring this for several days it seems to have settled down and is no longer logging the strange errors section.  Perhaps it was a result of something during the Ubuntu upgrade procedure that somehow took days to clear.

The only logwatch issue I have remaining is a large number of messages like this every day (but they aren't fail2ban errors):

```
dovecot: pop3-login: Login failed: Plaintext authentication disabled: user=<>, rip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, lip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, session=<Coc09jVzugd1Vk2q>: 1 Time(s)
```

I guess it is time for a new question.

Comment: I'm also having problems with logwatch after upgrading.  Mine will no longer email me reports :( Following.